# Office 365 Mail API: Admin access token to access everyone's emails

Tags: azure, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, office365api

Is it possible for me to access everyone emails within my company using the Office 365 Mail API? I know I can access individuals, but hat requires me to be granted access to their emails and get their access tokens. I would like to be able to have an admin access token and be able to access everyone's emails. Any ideas whether this is possible or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible. We can register a Web application and/or Web API (default, known as a confidential client in OAuth2 parlance) an build a daemon service to retrieve all the messages for organization.

Here is an example that using the client credentials to request the token and get the messages from different users:

```
string authority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/msdnofficedev.onmicrosoft.com";
        string resource = "https://Graph.microsoft.com";
        string clientID = "";
        string clientSecret = "";
        AuthenticationContext ac = new AuthenticationContext(authority);
        AuthenticationResult ar = ac.AcquireToken(resource, new ClientCredential(clientID, clientSecret));

        HttpClient hc = new HttpClient();
        hc.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + ar.AccessToken);
        HttpResponseMessage hrm = await hc.GetAsync("https://Graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/fx@msdnofficedev.onmicrosoft.com/messages/");
        string content=await hrm.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        MessageBox.Show(content);

        HttpResponseMessage hrm2 = await hc.GetAsync("https://Graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/user1@msdnofficedev.onmicrosoft.com/messages/");
        content = await hrm2.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        MessageBox.Show(content);
```

For more detail about register application in Azure AD, you can follow link below:
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-integrating-applications/#BKMK_Native

Comment: After building daemon service, is there also a way to setup Notification Webhook for all users at once ? https://dev.outlook.com/restapi/concepts/webhooks. We are planning to use this webhooks to call our REST API when there are inbound emails so we can filter as per our need. Thanks.

Comment: No. The Office 365 webhook is user-level. You may submit the feedback from [here](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/) if you require this feature.

Comment: thank you! i.e we have to setup the webhook for each individual users ? If so, is it doable programmatically? In that case, everytime new users are registered in our system, we can create a webhook subscriptions  automatically. You got what I am saying ?

Comment: Btw, what code base is this ? C# ? I'm trying to implement same thing using Java but I couldn't find a ref to AuthenticationContext. What library are you using ? Thanks

Comment: Yes, the code sample is write with Azure Active directory using C#. You can find the library for Java from [here](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-java).